# Difficulty understanding the output of my Regex function

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am trying to split the following type of strings:

```
"COM_RST                  :BOOL := FALSE;"
"COM_RST                  : DINT := 0;"
```

So I made this Regex function where I want to parse an indefinite amount of blankspaces followed by a double dot followed by either a blankspace or a letter.

```
Regex Rx = new Regex(@"[ ]*[:]([ ]|[A-Z])");
```

The aim is to split it in two, so that I would get the following:

```
sides[0] = "COM_RST";
sides[1] = "BOOL := FALSE;"
```

I am using

```
string[] sides = Rx.Split(inputStr).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```

Which seems to run for some of the inputs, however for the above mentioned one this is the output I get:

```
sides[0] = "        COM_RST";
sides[1] = "B";
sides[2] = "OOL := FALSE;";
```

Comment: Why not using the _pseudo_ `String.SubString(Indexof(":"))`? _if you want to solve one problem with regex, you got two problems_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `sides[1] = "B"` because your regex contains a *capturing group*: `([ ]|[A-Z])`. Once captured, this text is output as a separate element of the resulting list. See [this C# `Regex.Split` excerpt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

If you plan to only split with `spaces`+`:`+`spaces` before an uppercase ASCII letter, use a lookahead:

```
[ ]*:[ ]*(?=[A-Z])
```

Note the brackets are only needed if you are using a free spacing mode with `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`.

[image]

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=+*%3a+*(%3f%3d%5bA-Z%5d)&i=COM_RST++++++++++++++++++%3aBOOL+%3a%3d+FALSE%3b)

A non-regex alternative splitting a string into 2 parts with the first `:`:

```
var chunks = input.Split(new[] {':'}, 2).Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Ah I didnt need Regex after all! .Split(new[] { ':' }, 2) works like a charm thanks

Answer (score 0):

This regex works with your example: \s*:\s*(?!=)